# Função next_post_link() para posts da mesma categoria não funciona

Tags: wordpress

Preciso gerar um botão para o próximo post da categoria e estou usando o seguinte código

```
<?php next_post_link('%link','<span class="button-1">%title</span>',TRUE); ?>
```

Mas mas ele inclui posts de outras categorias mesmo setando o parâmetro $in_same_term como TRUE e excluindo outras categorias com o parâmetro $excluded_terms, modificar esses parâmetros não causa efeito nenhum no link gerado, somente os parâmetros $format e $link funcionam.

Inseri esse código em um arquivo content-news.php o qual é chamado dentro do single.php.

Comment: Você já tentou <?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE, '13' ); ?> substituindo  o 13 pe id da categoria, também tente dessa forma mas sem o id da categoria

Comment: É porque `wordpress` é um grande XGH utilizador de globais.

Comment: Tentei, o link não aparece.